# GNU make each subdirectory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following file hierarchy:

```
Makefile
dir1/
    script.sh
    other_files.txt
dir2/
    script.sh
    other_stuff.dat
dir3/
    script.sh
    other_data.csv
```

...where `script.sh` is a script that runs without producing any make-able output (e.g. `echo "Hello world!"`. In my real example, each `dir` is an R package).

I'm trying to create a Makefile that will run `script.sh` in each `dir`, but only if something in the directory has changed. What I tried so far is this:

```
DIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3
RUNFILES := $(DIRS:%=run.%)

.PHONY: all ${DIRS}

all: ${DIRS}

dir2: dir3

% : run.%

run.% : $(wildcard %/*)
    $(@D)/script.sh
    touch $@
```

...where each invocation of `script.sh` is followed by just touching a new `run.dirX` file (e.g. `dir/script1.sh; touch run.dir1`). But this doesn't work -- running `make all` just says there are no targets.

It seems like there should be a clean way to do this without the clunky solution of having a script generate the whole makefile...but I'm not sure what it is. Any thoughts?

Comment: You want Make to run the script if and only if nothing has changed? Usually Make does things only if something has changed. What you ask is possible, but the solution may be awkward.

Comment: Oops! I meant if anything has changed, in typical make fashion. Revised my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. We can eliminate a few unneeded steps and have the runfiles as the primary targets:

```
DIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3
RUNFILES := $(DIRS:%=run.%)

.PHONY: all
all: $(RUNFILES)
```

The only trick is that if we put `wildcard` in the prerequisite list, Make tends to expand it before deciding which targets to build-- when the pattern rule is still just a pattern rule, and there is no directory named "%" to scan. So we use `SECONDEXPANSION` and an extra '$' to get Make to defer the expansion until after it has chosen the stem:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
run.%: $$(wildcard %/*)
    @$*/script.sh
    @touch $@
```

Comment: `.SECONDEXPANSION` -- what sorcery is this!? Thank you, this worked beautifully!